# type HomeController is not a member of package controllers - compilation error

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

My Play Framework used to work until I rebuild the project. Then I get this error.

My problem is exactly the one described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40508995/type-is-not-a-member-of-package-controllers).

This is the top answer in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543960/play-framework-for-scala-compilation-errortype-application-is-not-a-member-of).

> Play 2.4, by default, generates a dependency injected router, unlike
>   previously, when it used a static router. You have two options, remove
>   the routesGenerator line from build.sbt so play will generate a static
>   router, or (better) make your controllers classes instead of objects,
>   and use dependency injection.

This also didn't work for me. There is no routesGenerator line build.sbt. HomeController is already a class.

build.sbt

```
name := """BookStoreApp"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.12.2"

libraryDependencies += guice

// Test Database
libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.194"

// Testing libraries for dealing with CompletionStage...
libraryDependencies += "org.assertj" % "assertj-core" % "3.6.2" % Test
libraryDependencies += "org.awaitility" % "awaitility" % "2.0.0" % Test

// Make verbose tests
testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Argument(TestFrameworks.JUnit, "-a", "-v"))
```

home controller

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;

public class HomeController extends Controller {
    public Result startGame() {
        return ok(gameView.render());
    }

    public Result statsPage(){
        return ok(statsView.render());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> There is no routesGenerator line build.sbt. HomeController is already a class.

So you need to add that line to the `build.sbt`

```
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

This line is default from 2.5 (can be omitted), but in 2.4 it must be in `built.sbt` if you want to use DI controllers.

And you want because you write `public Result startGame()` but `public static Result startGame()`